# PHP/MySQL Simple Checklist

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I currently have an internal intranet form that saves referral information from front line staff and makes it available to back office staff in a simple table. I have been asked to add check boxes to the form so the back office staff will know when certain steps in the referral process have been completed.

My question is, what would be the simplest way to add a check boxes that will stay checked on refresh if the staff has completed a certain step? Any help would be greatly appreciated, the bit of code below is where my table is generated. I have tried everything I can think of to make it work to no avail.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['subDate']   . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['mbr_name']  . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['acct']      . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['mbr_tel']   . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['mbr_email'] . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['alt_tel']   . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['msr_name']  . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['type']      . "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['cata']      . "</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, if you put your field names in an array (`$fields = array('subDate', 'mbr_name', ...);`, you can then just iterate over the array, and this entire blob of code would be about 4 lines long.

Comment: Best solution would probably be using AJAX and PHP together, if you already use it. A little note: unless you're sure at the 100% that no one will try to drop your tables, mysql is actually deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead (check documentation). Anyway, the basic idea is this one: use javascript (or jQuery) to send requests to server and populate the table. Create a little handler on the client that every X seconds checks if the value of the Database has changed (which is the value of the checkbox). If so, update the table.. That's just an idea :)